# Forward and backward process in pyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When I write a network, do I have to write the whole forward property in `nn.Module.forward()`? I mean if I do some operations outside the net, does grad correctly flow?

For example, I have two networks, in which the output of one is the input of the other(`net1 -> midresults -> net2`).

If I do some operations on midresults(`net1 -> midresults -> operations -> net2`), can (net1+net2) be trained end to end?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your operations are all compatible with pytorch tensors and [Autograd](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html) then yes your network will be trained end-to-end.

A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself : I'm I using tensors and pytorch operators end-to-end? If yes (and unless stated otherwise in the docs), you should be pretty safe.